# CircleCI connecting to wordpress through Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, rspec, circleci, rubypress

I have a test that connects to my wordpress account using rubypress through Rspec, it works fine when running rspec locally, but when the tests are run with Circle CI I get the following error:

```
1) ProjectAccount .wordpress_users
 Failure/Error: users = project_account.wordpress_users
 XMLRPC::FaultException:
   Incorrect username or password.
```

Do I need any specific settings to connect to wordpress, either on my WP account or my circle.yml file? I feel like this error is impossible since it works locally, it can't be wrong username/password combo error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't connect to external services in your tests!** While this might sound like a good idea due to the high degree of acuity it gives very slow tests and violates application boundaries. Good tests should also be deterministic - if you are using an external service "live" the data might actually change or the server might not respond which will break your tests.

When working with external data sources I usually use the [Webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) gem to mock out all external API requests. I sometimes use it with [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) which records actual requests and then plays back the canned response.